# discord.py How to make bot automatically send message on a specific day?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am working at my bot that is working with dates. I want my discord bot to send some message automatically, without command. For example, there is how to react on date with command:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

 @bot.command()
 async def badd(ctx): 
  today = date.today()
  d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m")
  if d1 == '10/03':
   await ctx.send('Its working')
  else:
   await ctx.send('False')
```

So when user enter " !badd " - bot send message. Is there any way to do it without sending a command to bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, You could use the `task` extension to create a loop for every period of time, but you would have to calculate it:

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

bot = commands.Bot("!")

channelId = #put the id of the channel in here

@tasks.loop(hours=168) #in this example for every week  
async def day_schedule():
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(channelId)
    await message_channel.send("Your message")
```